# Can I save Android VideoView stream buffer to a file on the storage?

Tags: android, android-videoview

For the case of playing video from a stream (i.e `"http://.../video.webm"`) using `VideoView`, once the buffer is full and the video is completely downloaded, can I save it somewhere on the storage? Do we have access to the buffer data?

Comment: @Warlock - I'm not sure it is a duplicate, since the answer for the first question can be a simple "No. android videoView doesnt handle caching" or "yes, its located at ...". While this question tries to figure out if we can access the buffer data.

Comment: both by you? same day? why dont you just edit the first question since they belong to related subject, though I voted up for question before seeing the other one

Comment: Try to use my sollution - AndroidVideoCache library. https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache

Answer (score 0):

> Do we have access to the buffer data?

No, sorry, you do not.